# Recover data from deleted opensearch domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops, opensearch

good morning,

Right now im facing a really odd situation.

My opensearch domain was deleted because someone decided to "comment" it in our cloudformation stack, there is a way to recover it back? or at least the data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple and plain answer **You can't**

According to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/opensearch-service/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteDomain.html)

> Deletes an Amazon OpenSearch Service domain and all of its data. You can't recover a domain after you delete it.